# SPSS Modeler SQL Query CASE Statement Link to Excel File

Tags: sql, spss-modeler

I'm using SPSS Modeler in order to connect to a database and run a SQL query.

Let's say I have a query like this

```
SELECT 

COUNT(distinct 
CASE WHEN "Product__Ord_Ln_" 
IN 
(
'Discount1',
'Discount2',
'Discount3',
/*
...
'Discount5000'
*/

)
THEN 1
END ) "DISC_ACCESS"
FROM PRODUCT_TABLE
```

As you can see, I have "Discounts" in my CASE statement that I have to add manually every time when I run to my query and have an update for these discounts.
At the same time, I have Excel file which I update regulary to store this information.

I don't have rights to create temp tables when I run my queries.

Is there any way to have a link between my SQL query and that Excel file, so I could run something like this

```
SELECT 

COUNT(distinct 
CASE WHEN "Product__Ord_Ln_" 
IN 
(
Excel_File_Discounts_Column.'Discount1',
Excel_File_Discounts_Column.'Discount2',
Excel_File_Discounts_Column.'Discount3',
/*
...
Excel_File.'Discount5000'
*/

)
THEN 1
END ) "DISC_ACCESS"
FROM PRODUCT_TABLE
```

Or any other efficient way to do this?